# pseudo-element :before is shown before jquery-animation is complete

Tags: jquery, html, css

in a menu for a mobile site I use .slideToggle(400) to show list-items on a touch/click of my menu-button. Every list-item has a pseudo-element :before with an image (an arrow). The problem is, that the pseudo-element (the pic of the arrow) is shown **before** the list-items of the menu are shown completely.

I tried to delay the :before with

```
$(document).off('click', '#menuicon').on('click', '#menuicon',function(e) {
  $('.class_of_list_item:before').delay(400).show('fast');
  $('#menu').slideToggle(400);
  ...
});
```

but that doesn't work. I have to mention that the problem only occurs, when I use "position:absolute" in my css at the pseudo-element :before.

```
.level1:before, .level2:before, .level3:before {
  content:url("/fileadmin/images/mobile/arrow_right_black.png");
  position:absolute;
  right:25px;
  padding-top:5px;
}
```

Does anyone have a clue? Thank you!!

Comment: Does `.class_of_list_item` have `position: relative;` set?  If not, setting `position: absolute;` on the `:before` would take the pseudo- element out of the document flow (and out of its containing `li`). Therefore the transition won't take it into account. Also, if you want to fix it by adding a `delay` before showing it, you should ensure that the `:before` pseudo-element had `display: none;` set initially.

Comment: Pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes are different things. They're not to be used interchangeably.

Comment: `Does .class_of_list_item have position: relative; set?` -> That was helpful! Now (with position:relative) it works without delay. Thank you very much!